# React: I'd like to make a list with two components order by datetime

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make one list page with tweets and retweets. I made data arrays different parts so I have to add something to create combine tweets and retweets order by datetime (new to old). However, it shows Tweet component and Retweet component one by one. How to make combine two arrays and make one list with the order by datetime?

My code now this...

> ```
> const {lists} = useContext(TweetApiContext) 
> const {retweets} =useContext(RetweetApiContext)
> const indexOfLastPage = currentPage * postsPerPage;
> const indexOfFirstPage = indexOfLastPage - postsPerPage;
> const currentTweets = lists.slice(indexOfFirstPage, indexOfLastPage)
> const orderByDateTweets = currentTweets.sort( (a, b) => {
>     return new Date(a.DateTime) - new Date(b.DateTime);});
>
> return(
>  {
>         orderByDateTweets.map((tweet, retweet) => 
>          <>
>          <TweetItem tweet={tweet} user={profile} />
>          <RetweetItem user={profile} retweet={retweets[retweet]} />
>          </>
>         )
>   }
> )
> ```

↓↓↓　This code display ↓↓↓

```
Tweet 5/20/2021 
Retweet 5/22/2021
Tweet 5/18/2021
Retweet 5/20/2021 ...
```

↓↓↓　But I'd like to make ↓↓↓

```
Retweet 5/22/2021
Retweet 5/20/2021
Tweet 5/20/2021
Retweet 5/19/2021
Tweet 5/18/2021　...
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for Date comparison and change the sort function with something like :

```
const orderByDateTweets = currentTweets.sort( (a, b) => {
const rowAValueDate = moment(a.DateTime, 'MMMM YYYY');
const rowBValueDate = moment(b.DateTime, 'MMMM YYYY');
if (rowAValueDate.isValid() && rowBValueDate.isValid()) {
            if (rowAValueDate.isAfter(rowBValueDate)) return 1;
            if (rowBValueDate.isAfter(rowAValueDate)) return -1;
            return 0;
      }
})
```

Comment: Thank you  Andres for answering my question. I tried that pattern but still not fixed the display pattern... Maybe I need to fix return() part?  or marge lists and retweets data then .sort() statement?